# android fails to verify when doing app linking

Tags: android, google-api, applinks

I use the **App Links Assistant** and followed the link [from here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html)

The app link fails when building the app.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

    <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

one Interesting thing i find out is when you

1. delete the line `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>`
2. build the app
3. add the line `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>` back
4. build again, the app link works.

**From the server side**:

I have found out that the link https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://example.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls will only call my server for the first time and return:

```
{
  "maxAge": "599.999999845s",
  "debugString": "********************* ERRORS *********************\n* Error: deadline_exceeded: Timeout occurred while fetching Web statements from https://example.com./.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is equivalent to 'https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json') using download from the web (ID 1).\n********************* INFO MESSAGES *********************\n* Info: No statements were found that match your query\n"
}
```

and then i refresh the link immediately, the response is success but there is no request received by my server. I am not sure how google api deal with it, I have read every question about app linking here.

Comment: Did you found any solutions to it?

Comment: I have this issue too, sometimes is working fine, sometimes has a timeout issue, how to fixed this issue? I have tested on 3 server, only 1 server got this issue.

Comment: Any news on Android 12 to somehow reverify the host? I still have the same issue.